# Suspend panning in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, scroll, panning

We use offset manipulation (script) to fix columns and rows in a table.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#xTableDiv").scroll(function() {
    setOffset($(this));
  });
});

function setOffset($div) {
  $div.find("td.fixedRow").css("top", $div.scrollTop());
  $div.find("td.fixedColumn").css("left", $div.scrollLeft());
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fpbo1dsx/

In history that works fine. 
Now is for vertical scrolling render html delayed.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Scroll-linked_effects

The only known way to change this, is set apz.disable_for_scroll_linked_effects to true (about:config) :-(

Is there a better way?

Comment: heureka :-) CSS   `td.fixedColumn {position: sticky; top:0px;}`, for more than one column use script to fix offset position  `$td.css("top", $td.position().top) `, on rows use "left" ;-)